# What are the file specifications of a compress .Z file?

Tags: compression, file-format

For some reason, I am unable to find what the specifications are for a .Z file even though I see many things supporting it. Why is it so hard to find online? I am very familiar with LZW compression but I don't know how it's implemented in the "compress" utility.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `man compress` the compression level is dependent on the size of the file, the number of bits per code, and the distribution of common substrings.  But typically the compression is between 50-60% precent.

Comment: You may want to point out that `compress` has a really poor compression ratio.

Comment: That's good but I am looking for how the codes are packaged into the file and other specifications like what the clear code is.